# Simple date conversion to ASP Classic from ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, date

How to do the same stuff using Classic ASP?
I mean, is it possible to do it in one row like in .Net?

```
string str1 = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
string str2 = DateTime.Now.ToString("H:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `yyyMMdd` make it one row

```
<%= Year(Now) & Right("0" & Month(Now), 2) & right("0" & Day(Now), 2) %>
**OR**
<%= DatePart("yyyy",Now) & Right("0" & DatePart("m",Now), 2) & right("0" & DatePart("d",Now), 2) %>
```

For `H:mm:ss`

```
<%= Hour(Now) & ":" & Right("0" & Minute(Now), 2) & ":" & right("0" & Second(Now), 2) %>
**OR**
<%= DatePart("h",Now) & Right("0" & DatePart("n",Now), 2) & right("0" & DatePart("s",Now), 2) %>
```

You might look at this here briefly explain about date parsing in vbScript.
https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/22/Date-formatting-in-VBScript